# SharePoint Online read/write on premise Dynamics AX data

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, wcf, spfx, wcf-rest

Currently i'm working with a customer having Dynamics AX on-premise and SharePoint 2013 on-premise web portal. They have built a custom WCF service to get data from Dynamics AX (employee, client, HR etc.,) and displaying the data in a SharePoint webpart. For example, employee name drop down control show employee names data fetched from Dynamics AX via WCF service.

Now they are planning to move to SharePoint online and want to use this form in SPO. The have configured an Azure AD Application Proxy pointing to on-premise WCF service as shown below.

[image]

What options are available to move this webpart to SPO and still able to access on-premise Dynamics AX data via Azure app proxy.

> Another requirement is also write back to DAX (for example, to update contact details)

What are the Options?

1. Do I need to rewrite this webpart using Add-in model ?
2. Do I need to create a client web part (SPFx ??)
3. Any other approach???

What is the best reference architecture for this requirement?

Comment: How is the proxy/web service secured? If they're secured using AAD and you can use OAuth implicit flow, then you could build a SharePoint Framework client-side web part. Otherwise you would have to build an add-in to complete the authentication and be able to access the information from the web service.